# IText - BarcodeQRCode making the background color transparent

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to set the background color of my QR Code using iText into a transparent background, however it does not work. Shows only white bars and black background.

What i have done so far:

My Code Snippet:

```
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("sample message on qr", 100, 100, null);
    java.awt.Image qrImage = qrcode.createAwtImage(Color.WHITE,new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    Image finalImage = Image.getInstance(writer, qrImage, 1);
    finalImage.setAbsolutePosition(positionX, positionY);
    cb.addImage(finalImage);
```

I have already generated my QR code and produced a PDF, however, when using

> qrcode.createAwtImage(Color.WHITE,new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

It does not produce an alpha background, instead it only shows a black background color.

I have also tried:

> java.awt.Image qrImage =
>   qrcode.createAwtImage(Color.WHITE,Color.OPAQUE);

But obviously, my arguments are incorrect.

Help will be most appreciated, i've been working on this for a day now.

I have also tried Graphics, Graphics2g, converting it into BufferedImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the assignment of `finalImage` to the following works:

```
Image finalImage = Image.getInstance(qrImage, null)
```

I don't know why using the `getInstance` method that takes a `PdfWriter` as first argument ruins the transparency, though...

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this problem like this:

```
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("sample message on qr", 100, 100, null);
Image image = qrcode.getImage();
Image mask = qrcode.getImage();
mask.makeMask();
image.setImageMask(mask);
document.add(image);
```

There may be an AWT solution too, but I'm more familiar with native PDF solutions than with using an AWT workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Also works like magic, but i'd like to change the colors of the qr code that's why i'm using AWT. However can you do it in your example?

Comment: It's probably possible, but I currently don't have the time to look it up. The other answer to this question confirms that there's an AWT solution too. It's a good way to meet your requirement.